# SSIS Data Tools for SQL Server 2014 (none of vb.net script tasks are working, even with default code)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2014

I have installed SQL Server 2014 Data Tools. When I add the script task and use C#, it work. But when I add script task and choose vb.net 2012, and then clicked on edit script and save.

After that click ok and getting this error message for all scripts, please note that I have not even added vb.net code yet.

scripts contained in the package have compilation errors. do you want to save changes?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think you can mix languages like this in a project. Maybe someone else has some better insight.

Comment: sorry, I am not mixing but trying to code using vb.net 2012 in SSIS 2014 data tools but none of the scripts are compiling, even with skeleton code (generated by the wizard)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thanks Tab and Jacob, I am only getting this error "scripts contained in the package have compilation errors. do you want to save changes?"

Comment: Is your SSDT2014 install an upgrade to a previous version, or a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I reinstalled SSDT and now all vb.net scripts are working.